# GTM Callback firing multiple times

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've followed the Google docs to add GTM tags to my site. For some reason the call back is firing 3 times, however, I only have this tag on the page.

```
  window.dataLayer.push({
         'event': 'add_expense',
         'eventCallback': function () {
                             alert('wtf');
                          }
         });
```

Anyone have any clues on why this may be?

Comment: You need to provide more than just a code snippet, a link to the page hosted online would be the best way forward for people to help.

Comment: Since this question relates directly to GTM a snippet should be enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be you have multiple GTM containers on the page, including plugins.  You can check to see if the callback is being passed different containers ids:

```
'eventCallback': function (id) {
                         alert(id);
                      }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find GTM docs but couldn't get this. 

That's solved it after hours of testing :)

Comment: @shamaseen i checked the gtm container id and then invoke call back that i needed only for that container

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after enabling GA4 in the page. Seems like it is using same container and rules as GTM and caused callbacks to fire twice. My solution:

```
const buildGtmCallback = (callback) => {
 //GA4 is also a container, so need to fire callbacks only once, for GTM container
 //GA4 containerId starts with G-
 return (containerId) => {
    if (containerId.startsWith("GTM-") && typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
 }
}
```

And then whatever you wish to be fired only once:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'add_expense',
     'eventCallback': buildGtmCallback(function () {
                         alert('wtf');
                      })
     });
```

This solution will also work if you have multiple GTM containers by modifying `containerId.startsWith("GTM-")` and replace “GTM-“ with the container ID you wish the event to fire for. However in that case you won’t be sure event was fired for both containers, just that one